# DAC datasheet term confusion: FS-1LSB

Tags: datasheet, dac

In the Digital to analog converter HP16BME, I keep stumbling into " +FS - 1LSB " and I'm not sure what it means.

I mean, I still don't know the exact scale value because I don't know what FS stands for and what they mean by 1LSB in this example

[image]

Comment: The DAC is set up so that full scale voltage corresponds to an input of `0x10000` and not `0xFFFF`. So the highest voltage it can produce is slightly less than 10 V.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"FS" means full-scale, which may be determined by an external voltage. "LSB" means Least Significant Bit - in this case, the voltage represented by one least significant bit. In a 16 bit DAC like yours, that's 1/2<sup>16</sup> of the full range.

Thus, "+FS-1LSB" means "full scale voltage less one least significant bit". For a full scale voltage of 10 volts, that's 10 volts - (1/2<sup>16</sup> * 10 volts) = 9.9985 volts.